# Strengthen specific links between two nodes D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/gp0u5rLu/75/

You can also see from this image :

[image]

The problem here is that to curve the path, we use a node as the center point of the path, which the path uses to curve towards. See here :

```
function positionLink(d) {
    return "M" + d[0].x + "," + d[0].y + // source node
      "Q" + d[1].x + "," + d[1].y + // middle node
      " " + d[2].x + "," + d[2].y; // target node
  }
```

Position link is called in the tick() function. As you can see the middle node, `d[1]`, is used as the point to curve towards. This is kept close to the source and target nodes as there are also edges connected between source and middle node and also target and middle node. See below image :

[image]

These edges stop the node floating away and keep it relatively close.

In my code this can cause issues where when the nodes are close together (source and target), the invisible nodes tend to float off more than necessary.

I thought that increasing the strength between the source - middle node and target - middle node may solve this issue. Is it possible to increase the strength of specific links ?

Comment: Doesn't [`link.strength()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_strength) solve your problem?

Comment: In [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_strength) you can read:
`The strength accessor is invoked for each link, being passed the link and its zero-based index. The resulting number is then stored internally, such that the strength of each link is only recomputed when the force is initialized or when this method is called with a new strength, and not on every application of the force.` So this might be your lead on how to manipulate this.